# Letter Spacing in TextFieldForm in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add letter spacing in textfieldform widget just like in Text widget there is an option of letter spacing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want letter spacing in normal text, use style property as shown below:

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(
    letterSpacing: 2.0,
  ),
),
```

If you want letter spacing in label text, use labelstyle property in input decoration as shown below

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Test',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
       letterSpacing: 2.0,
    ),
 ),
),
```

In the same way you can style hint text too using hint style property.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `TextStyle` widget:

```
TextFormField(
  style : TextStyle(letterSpacing : 2.0),
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `letterSpacing:` inside of `TextStyle`.

```
TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0)
```